# Why does mutate doesn't work if we put ifelse of results of types both "character" and "numeric"?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I want to create a custom column to a dataframe grouped by **level** which will be the **mean** of 2 variables. When there is a missing data, I need a sign of masking, like: "--". Example:

```
df <-  data.frame(level= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,6,7,5,4,2), var1=c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,6,7,5,4), var2 = c(2,NA,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,6,7,5))
```

## doesn't work:

```
df  %>%
  group_by(level) %>% 
  mutate(result = ifelse(is.na(var1) | is.na(var2), "--", mean(c(var1,var2))))
```

## doesn't work:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(level) %>% 
  mutate(result = ifelse(!(is.na(var1) | is.na(var2)), mean(c(var1,var2)), "--" ))
```

## doesn't give an error:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(level) %>% 
  mutate(result = ifelse(is.na(var1) | is.na(var2), mean(c(var1,var2)), "--" ))
```

The error I get in 2 first cases is:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `result` can't be converted from numeric to character
```

Can you tell me what am I missing, how does mutate work so I can actually obtain what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you really need. I'll update my answer when you post your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `ifelse` documentation -

> ifelse(test, yes, no)
>
> ifelse returns a vector of the same length and attributes (including
>   dimensions and "class") as test and data values from the values of yes
>   or no. The mode of the answer will be coerced from logical to
>   accommodate first any values taken from yes and then any values taken
>   from no

Basically you can't mix characters and numbers for yes/no values. It is not a good idea mix characters and numbers in the same variable anyways. Consider using `NA_real_` instead of `--`. If you must do it your way then you can try using `as.character(mean(c(var1,var2)))` but now your means are returned as characters.

```
df  %>%
  group_by(level) %>% 
  mutate(result = ifelse(is.na(var1) | is.na(var2), "--", as.character(mean(c(var1,var2)))))

# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   level [8]
   level  var1  var2 result
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
 1     1     1     2 1.5   
 2     2     1    NA --    
 3     3     2     1 1.5   
 4     4     3     2 4.25  
 5     5     4     3 5     
 6     6     5     4 6.25  
 7     7     6     5 6.25  
 8     8     7     6 7     
 9     8     8     7 7     
10     6     8     8 6.25  
11     7     6     8 6.25  
12     5     7     6 5     
13     4     5     7 4.25  
14     2     4     5 NA
```

**Note -**

You can use `write.csv(df, "report.csv", na = "--")` if you only want to replace `NA` with `"--"` in your report.

Comment: Ok, that exaplains a lot. I need "--" cause the export is used later by macro for the report and it has to be "--". I guess with a character it will work as I only need a csv export and in csv the column is a general format still. Thanks!

Comment: `write.csv` takes an argument `na` where you can add the string to use for missing values in the data. Basically you can add `na = "--"` argument to your `write.csv` statement.

Comment: Got it, I just checked in the documentation, I didn't know that, but it's very useful. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer worked for you, consider marking it as correct using tick mark at top left.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `case_when`

```
 df %>%
   group_by(level) %>% 
   mutate(result = case_when(is.na(var1)|is.na(var2) ~ "--", 
                       TRUE ~ as.character(mean(c(var1, var2)))))
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   level [8]
#   level  var1  var2 result
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1     1     1     2 1.5   
# 2     2     1    NA --    
# 3     3     2     1 1.5   
# 4     4     3     2 4.25  
# 5     5     4     3 5     
# 6     6     5     4 6.25  
# 7     7     6     5 6.25  
# 8     8     7     6 7     
# 9     8     8     7 7     
#10     6     8     8 6.25  
#11     7     6     8 6.25  
#12     5     7     6 5     
#13     4     5     7 4.25  
#14     2     4     5 <NA>
```